# Memory Allocation Freeing

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, malloc, free

I'm currently writing a linked list and trying to free up memory allocations when I delete a node. However, after hours of trying to do this, I can't seem to get a clean valgrind output.

```
void * pop(struct List *list)
{
    if(list->head == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    struct Node * tempNode = list->head->next;                                                                                                            
    free(list->head);
    list->head = tempNode;
    ...
}
```

I'm allocating the space by saying:

```
addNode(struct List *list, void *element){
    struct Node *node;
    node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ....
}
```

Basically in the pop function I want to take out the head of the list and make the head's next node the new head. I want to deallocate the memory that was given to head.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woah, your `malloc` isn't correct. You have:

```
(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

What you need is:

```
(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

In your original code, you are only allocating enough for a pointer. But you are trying allocate a `Node` object.

Answer (score 1):

```
node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
```

Allocate space for the thing pointed to by `node`.

Don't cast the return value of `malloc`. Doing so can mask the failure to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct. Or are there some leaks in the other places? Or do you free the element itself as the parameter passed in ?